# How to get Scalar Evolution analysis in a LLVM LoopPass?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I need to get hold of `ScalarEvolution` object inside LLVM loop pass. I know that we can get it from
`LoopStandardAnalysisResults` object while using new pass manager. Is it possible to get the scalarEvolution analysis using old / legacy loop pass ?

Comment: If nothing else, you can just instantiate that analysis' class and ask for it. The analysis structure is basically just caching, to improve performance because analyses are used by so many passes. If the caching doesn't work for you, ignore it for now and revisit the issue if/when that's a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some code search I found we can do like below :

```
  bool runOnLoop(Loop *L, LPPassManager &LPM) override {

    auto *SE = getAnalysisIfAvailable<ScalarEvolutionWrapperPass>();
}
```